# When trying to drop a column from my dataset using pandas, i get the error "['churn'] not found in axis"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want the x to be all the columns except "churn" column.
But when i do the below i get the "['churn'] not found in axis" error, eventhough i can see the column name when i write "print(list(df.column))"
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/utkusenel/Documents/Data Analyzing/data.csv", header=0)
print(df.head())
print(df.columns)
print(len(df.columns))
x = df.drop(["churn"], axis=1) ## this is the part it gives the error
```

I am adding a snippet of my dataset as well:

```
account_length;area_code;international_plan;voice_mail_plan;number_vmail_messages;total_day_minutes;total_day_calls;total_day_charge;total_eve_minutes;total_eve_calls;total_eve_charge;total_night_minutes;total_night_calls;total_night_charge;total_intl_minutes;total_intl_calls;total_intl_charge;number_customer_service_calls;churn;
1;KS;128;area_code_415;no;yes;25;265.1;110;45.07;197.4;99;16.78;244.7;91;11.01;10;3;2.7;1;no
2;OH;107;area_code_415;no;yes;26;161.6;123;27.47;195.5;103;16.62;254.4;103;11.45;13.7;3;3.7;1;no
3;NJ;137;area_code_415;no;no;0;243.4;114;41.38;121.2;110;10.3;162.6;104;7.32;12.2;5;3.29;0;no
```

Comment: 2 lines before that you `print(df.columns)`. What **exactly** does that show?

Comment: Please notice that code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and should not be included here (just creates unnecessary clutter), as well as the irrelevant imports (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your df snippet is separeted with ';' (semi colon). If that is what your actual data looks like, then probably your csv is being read wrong. Please try adding `sep=';'` to read_csv function.

`df = pd.read_csv("/Users/utkusenel/Documents/Data Analyzing/data.csv", header=0, sep=';')`

I also suggest print `df.columns` again and check if there is a leading or trailing `whitespace` in the column name for `churn`.

Comment: But the problem is, it doesn't even notices the columns. When i print len(df.columns) it equals 1 eventhough i have 19 columns... @FaridJafri

Comment: I see in the above comment that you put the df snippet with ';' (semi colon) separated values. If that is what your actual data looks like, then probably your csv is being read wrong. Please try adding `sep=';'` to read_csv function.
`df = pd.read_csv("/Users/utkusenel/Documents/Data Analyzing/data.csv", header=0, sep=';')`

Comment: Yess it worked. Such a stupid mistake i made... Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, if you could please mark this question answered, that'd be great!

Comment: @UtkuŞenel If you think the answer below answers your question, please make sure to mark it answered by clicking on the check mark below upvote and downvote buttons.